# What does "I like ducks :)" mean when it is used as a status?

Tags: american-english

Does it give multiple meanings out of it using typoglycemia? Thanks.

I saw it on a social profile and it appeared to me as,

```
"I like dicks :)"
```

Comment: A status on what site?  What typoglycemic word or phrase do you think it represents?  Please provide your research and examples so we can help you. :-)

Comment: I like ducks, too. It is not an anagram, nor an acronym of anything exciting. There is a six-wheel-drive amphibious truck called a DUKW; I think, though, it most likely means he is fond any of numerous relatively small and short-necked web-footed swimming birds characterized by broad, flat bills.

Comment: I believe you've stumbled across the semantic phenomenon known as a non-sequitor.  Some people use non-sequitor items to appear cool or humorous, particularly as their statuses on social media.  Read my profile on here and you'll see an example.

Comment: If they had used a winky face instead of a smiley face, they might have meant there is a double meaning, or maybe that it was an in-joke for the benefit of certain people. As it is, it really just seems to mean they like ducks. To know for sure, you would have to ask the person who posted it.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the person just likes ducks.

The smiley seems to reinforce the idea that this is just a light-hearted expression of affection for our web-footed friends. It's hard to interpret it any other way.

Answer (score 0):

If the person is from New Zealand, where  "dick" is often pronounced "duck", your initial reading could be correct after all.